# How would websockets differ with TCP and UDP?

Tags: sockets, websocket, tcp, udp

From my knowledge, in HTTP over TCP, you receive an acknowledgment every time and make sure it reaches in order. That's the whole point of why anyone would use TCP over UDP. But, how would WebSockets over TCP act differently from WebSockets over UDP?

From the sources, I have read WebSockets over TCP don't have acknowledgment. So how are WebSockets over TCP different from UDP? Does WebSocket over UDP even exist?

Comment: There's no such thing as websockets over UDP at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

> I have read WebSockets over TCP don't have acknowledgment.

WebSockets over TCP are just an additional layer on top of an already reliable layer (TCP), so they don't have extra acknowledgements of their own, i.e. they rely on the acknowledgements of the lower layer for this.

> Does WebSocket over UDP even exist?

No.